# Transform list in a JSON, then manipulate the json and add nested nodes with Java

Tags: java, json, list, nodes

I have a list of objects:

```
List<ScuolaEntity> result = scuolaService.getAllScuoleEntity();
```

I would like to convert the list in a json object, I have tried with gson, with JSONObject and even with JsonNode, but I couldn't find a way to manipulate deeply this json.

This is the actual json:

```
[
    {
        "codiceMeccanografico": "RMAT123456",
        "anno": 2022,
        "sezione": "A",
        "nome": "PIETRO",
        "cognome": "BUCCIANTI",
        "classe": {
            "anno": 2022,
            "sezione": "A"
        }
    },
    {
        "codiceMeccanografico": "RMAT123456",
        "anno": 2022,
        "sezione": "A",
        "nome": "LEONARDO",
        "cognome": "FANTE",
        "classe": {
            "anno": 2022,
            "sezione": "A",
            "ubicazione": "PIANO TERRA"
        }
    }
]
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
{
  "scuola": {
    "codiceMeccanografico": "RMAT123456",
    "classe": {
      "anno": 2022,
      "sezione": "A",
      "studenti": [
        {
          "nome": "PIETRO",
          "cognome": "BUCCIANTI"
        },
        {
          "nome": "MARIO",
          "cognome": "ROSSI"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't manipulate json like that, even if it's possible, it will be hard and error prone. Create a class, reflecting the structure you need(this looks like grouping by some attribute), apply the operations to transform the list to this new object, and then serialize to json the result.

Comment: BTW your question is getting downvotes because you did not show any attempt to solve this. Add some of the code you tried and explain where it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create classes that have the structure you want, and map the values into it, e.g.

```
public class Scuola {
    private String codiceMeccanografico;
    private Classe classe;
}

public class Classe {
    private int anno;
    private String sezione;
    private List<Studente> studenti;
}

public class Studente {
    private String nome;
    private String cognome;
}
```

Then do:

```
Scuola map(ScuolaEntity scuolaEntity) {
    Scuola scuola = new Scuola();
    scuola.setCodiceMeccanografico(scuolaEntity.getCodiceMeccanografico());

    Classe classe = new Classe();
    classe.setAnno(scuolaEntity.getAnno());
    // etc.
    scuola.setClasse(classe);

    // etc.
    return scuola;
}
```

Comment: I can't build my model as I wish because it's a hibernate Entity

Comment: You don't have to change the ScuolaEntity at all. Just create separate classes and copy the values from the entity into them as shown above. Then map the result to JSON and see if it matches.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try it!